# Validate date on the format "yyMMdd" in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, validation

I'm trying to write a custom ASP.NET field validator which makes sure the input is a valid date on the format "yyMMdd".

How do I do that?

Comment: @John Saunders: I was using `ParseExact` but couldn't figure out the arguments to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `DateTime.ParseExact("091223", "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

**EDIT**
Woops, sorry, didn't see the ASP.NET bit. AFAIK you can make custom validators in ASP.NET? This could be the base of it, and there is also a "TryParseExact" version of the DateTime call, which would allow you to check without exception.

Comment: In all cases, for validation code (i.e. invalid format expected) the Try* methods are a better choice.